# Sum datagridview cells with comma generates a format exception

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm using this code for sum datagridview's cells.

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
sum += Convert.ToInt32 (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
}
int count_row = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;

label1.Text = (sum.ToString());
```

The code works well if I just use numbers. However, when I use commas, e.g., 1,34 and 2,20, it says that format exception was unhandled.

Comment: Exactly what would you like to happen with `1,34` when you convert it to an `Int32`?

Comment: use decimal instead int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is quite simple, juste do it with decimals.

```
Decimal sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
sum += Convert.Decimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
}
int count_row = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;

label1.Text = (sum.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify the line as shown below:

```
sum += Convert.ToInt32 (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString().Replace(",",""));
```

and it should work with commas as well.

Comment: Thank you sir but it says:does not contain definition for contain

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
double sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
    sum += double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString().Replace(',','.'));
}
int count_row = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;

label1.Text = (((int)sum).ToString());
```

Comment: object does not contain definition for replace and no extension method "replace" accepting a first argument of type object